# Covariance for a multivariate Bayesian Additive Regression Tree

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, multivariate-regression, bart

[Chipman, George, and McCullogh (2010)](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1273584455) state that:

> One can also extend the sum-of-trees model to a multivariate framework such as:
>   $$
> (29) \qquad\qquad Y_i = h_i\left( x_i \right) + \varepsilon_i, \quad \left(\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2, \dots, \varepsilon_p\right) \sim N\left( 0, \Sigma \right)
> $$
>   where each $h_i$ is a sum of trees and $\Sigma$ is a $p$ dimensional covariance matrix. ... The multivariate version of BART (29) is easily fit by drawing each $h^*_i$ given i given $\{h^*_j\}_{j \neq i}$ and $\Sigma$, and then drawing $\Sigma$ given all the $h^*_i$ (p. 295).

but do not explain how. Am I supposed to assume an inverse-Wishart prior on $\Sigma$? If so, would I then just draw from $Wishart^{-1}\left(YY^T + \Psi, N+\nu \right)$? (where $N$ is the sample size, $Y$ is the response vector, and $\Psi$ and $\nu$ are the prior parameters; as per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution#Conjugate_distribution)).

The univariate version of the model has an inverse-chi-square distribution (p. 272).

**Citation:**

Chipman, Hugh A.; George, Edward I.; McCulloch, Robert E. BART: Bayesian additive regression trees. The Annals of Applied Statistics 4 (2010), no. 1, 266--298. doi:10.1214/09-AOAS285. http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1273584455.